# Filter whole table and not shown paginated table snipset

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, pagination

at first you should know, that I am not very familar with html and javascript.
I created a table in html and added search functionality with simple text and multiple chosen elements and a alternating row coloring.
That works pretty fine.
Now my table grow up to ~ 300 rows and I wanna give the users the possibility to view the table page by page.
I found datatable which looks pretty fine, but know my search will only work for the shown paginated table and not for the whole table.
How can I search in the whole table and not only in the shown snipset?

```
<label style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;font-weight:normal">Title </label>
<input style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;font-weight:normal" type="text" id="searchTitle" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="Search in title.." title="Type in a text">
<label style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;font-weight:normal"> Abbreviation </label>
<input style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;font-weight:normal" type="text" id="searchAbbr" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="Search in abbreviation.." title="Type in a text">
<label style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;font-weight:normal"> Author </label>
<select data-placeholder="select an author for filter" multiple class="chosen-select" id="searchAuthor" name="searchAuthor" onchange="mySearch()" width="25%"></select>
<br/>
<br/>

<table class="tg" id="tableData">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 35%">
        <col style="width: 100px">
        <col style="width: 30%">
        <col style="width: 100px">
        <col style="width: 12%">
        <col style="width: 70px">
        <col style="width: 10%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="parent">
            <th class="header-left">Title</th>
            <th class="header-center">Abbreviation</th>
            <th class="header-left">Annex<br/><span style="font-weight:normal;font-size:small">(Please refer to the trace matrix for valid-from date, author and version for attachments.)</span></th>
            <th class="header-center">Valid from</th>
            <th class="header-left">Author</th>
            <th class="header-center">Version</th>
            <th class="header-left">Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

a lot of table rows

````
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   -->

 
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#searchAuthor").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 10
        , no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
        , width: "20%"
        })

    $(document).ready(function () {
        updateAlternateRowColors();

        var  table, tr, listSearchAuthor, authors, i, j, td, txtValue, found;
        
        table = document.getElementById("tableData");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        listSearchAuthor = $("#searchAuthor");
        
        authors = []; 
        
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.length > 0) {
                    found = false;
                    
                    for (j = 0; j < authors.length; j++)
                    {
                        if (txtValue == authors[j])
                        {
                            found = true;
                            j = authors.length;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found == false) {
                        authors.push(txtValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        authors.sort();
        for (j = 0; j < authors.length; j++)
        {
            listSearchAuthor.append('<option style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;font-weight:normal" value="' + authors[j] + '">' + authors[j] + '</option>');
        }
        listSearchAuthor.trigger("chosen:updated");

        $("#tableData").DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            "sorting": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "info": false
        });
    }
    );
</script>

<script>
function mySearch() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, txtValue, foundTitle, foundAbbr, foundAuthor, listAuthor;
    filterTitle = document.getElementById("searchTitle").value.toUpperCase();
    filterAbbr = document.getElementById("searchAbbr").value.toUpperCase();
    listSearchAuthor = $("#searchAuthor");
    table = document.getElementById("tableData");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        foundTitle = false;
        foundAbbr = false;
        foundAuthor = false;

        if (tr[i].className != "parent"){
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterTitle) > -1) {
                    foundTitle = true;
                }
            }
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterAbbr) > -1) {
                    foundAbbr = true;
                }
            }
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (listSearchAuthor[0].selectedOptions.length > 0) {
                    for (j = 0; j < listSearchAuthor[0].selectedOptions.length; j++) {
                        if (txtValue.indexOf(listSearchAuthor[0].selectedOptions[j].value) > -1) {
                            foundAuthor = true;
                            j = listSearchAuthor[0].selectedOptions.length;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    foundAuthor = true;
                }
            }

            if (foundTitle && foundAbbr && foundAuthor) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
    updateAlternateRowColors();
}
</script>

<script>
function updateAlternateRowColors(){
    //for table row
    var table, tr, i, j, found;
    j=0;
    table = document.getElementById("tableData");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (tr[i].className != "parent"){
            if (tr[i].style.display == ""){
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    tr[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.backgroundColor = "#f9f9f9";
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>```

Who can help? 
Any help appreciated!!!
````

Comment: DataTables has extensive APIs for searching/filtering functionalities, maybe you don't need to re-invent the wheel. I suggest you to look at their excellent documentation https://datatables.net/reference/api/search() / https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search

Comment: I agree with the above comment, but just to add - if you want to restrict your search to a particular column, or if you want to search using multiple columns, take a look at [column filtering](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html). The example shows text search but it's possible to have `select` dropdowns or even a mixture of both.

Comment: That is right I can use the DataTable functionality for searching. I changed my code to
`<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tableData").DataTable({
   "searching": false,
   "sorting": false,
   "lengthChange": false,
   "info": false
  });

  var  table;
  table = $("#tableData").DataTable();
  
  $("#searchTitle").on('keyup', function() {
   table.column(0).search( this.value).draw();
  });
`
But table will not shrink after entering a search vaue

Comment: OK. That can't work. I set searching to false because I wanna hide the search box of DataTables. With setting to true it works. Now I have a look how I can hide the search box of DataTables